# Disabling OID in AWS Redshift

Tags: excel, postgresql, amazon-web-services, odbc, amazon-redshift

I'm running into an ODBC issue with OIDS from Redshift

I have to build dynamic reports in excel using an ODBC connection and it says it can't find the Oid column.

I'm waiting to see if the DBA can change the default settings but every PostgreSQL command to disable OIDS doesn't work in Redshift. Suggestions? Please, no comments on Excel as reporting tool, it's all I've got at the moment.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
CREATE TABLE (
...
) WITHOUT OIDS;

CREATE TABLE (
...
) WITH ( OIDS = FALSE );

alter table [tablename] SET WITHOUT OIDS;
```

Comment: Redshift is based on a heavily modified extremely old PostgreSQL version. It's quite likely that it just doesn't support what you want. Most people who're using Redshift should probably be using RDS PostgreSQL instead.

Comment: I'm glad you said that as it does feel extremely limiting in functionality, intermittent performance and timeout issues.  I'll look into the performance and cost-benefit of rds vs redshift.

Comment: Timeouts are probably just NAT conntracking; enable keepalives. The rest ... yeah, thats part Redshift and partly just what to expect on cloud hosting without exclusive tenancy.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem and we fixed it by changing the way Excel setup the connection to AWS Redshift. Instead of creating a connection `From Microsoft Query`, we did it **`From Data Connection Wizard`**:

[image]

By the way, this allow you to see the connection string (which by default includes `FAKEOIDINDEX=0;SHOWOIDCOLUMN=0`).

PS: More informations o[n what are OID and why Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625585/sql-postgres-oids-what-are-they-and-why-are-they-useful) (Microsoft Query) is using OIDS to handle rows (it's a king of unique row ID). But if you write your own SQL requests, Excel should not annoy you with OIDS..

Hope that helps..