# Can we setup a table in postgres to always view the latest inserts first?

Tags: postgresql

Right now when I create a table and do a

```
select * from table
```

I always see the first insert rows first. I'd like to have my latest inserts displayed first. Is it possible to achieve with minimal performance impact?

Comment: There is no such thing as a the "first" or "latest" row in a table. Rows in a table are ***NOT*** sorted. The ***only*** way to get a specific sort order is to use `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Postgres uses an internal field called OID that can be sorted by. Try the following.

```
select *,OID from table order by OID desc;
```

There are some limitations to this approach as described in [SQL, Postgres OIDs, What are they and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625585/sql-postgres-oids-what-are-they-and-why-are-they-useful)

> Apparently the OID sequence "does" wrap if it exceeds 4B 6. So in essence it's a global counter that can wrap. If it does wrap, some slowdown may start occurring when it's used and "searched" for unique values, etc.
>
> See also https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_an_OID.3F

NB - in more recent version of Postgres this could be deprecated ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS )

Although you should be able to create tables with OID even in the most recent version if done explicitly on table create as per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtable.html

Although the behaviour you are observing in the CLI appears consistent, it isn't a standard and cannot be depended on. If you are regularly needing to manually see the most recently added rows on a specific table you could add a timestamp field or some other sortable field and perhaps even wrap the query into a stored function .. I guess the approach  depends on your particular use case.

Comment: By default tables are created without an oid

Comment: yes - for more recent version of postgres that is true.

Comment: "*more recent*" - means anything released after 2005

Comment: I thought the answer may be useful but if you think my answer is of no value I will delete it

Comment: It looks as though oid can be configured on table creation even with most recent version so I believe that my answer is valid in the context of the available information